# Building a GUI for desktop&web

Tags: web-apps, gui, gui-builder

I am looking for a tool to build a GUI.

this GUI

- allows the user to set some settings; upload a file
- connects to other webservices
- gets frequently updated by these services and shows the result to the user
- conserves resources
- can run in a webbrowser
- single webpage: no reloading/refreshing of the site

I hope for a tool to build a GUI without much effort. Ive tried electron, but its for desktop only. I've thought about php/ajax, but I don't want to build everything from the scratch.
Hope for some suggestions/thoughts.

for example: I would love to do have a tool to build a powerful gui like lichess which has everything I am looking for.

Comment: Nowhere in your requirements appears desktop, are you wanting to use a normal desktop program or a webpage? Also, pretty much any web GUI framework can do that, can you narrow your needs to something more specific?

Answer (score -1):

You can try Microsoft Visual Studio Community. Free and Easy to use. You can achieve all these functionalities without much efforts.
Link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: How does this help create a GUI for a web app?

Comment: @Anonymous, AI?